# Connecting to MongoDb Atlas using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to MongoDb Atlas using URL string provided by atlas as :

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://user:@contactlistcluster-hk1w5.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database!");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Connection failed!");
    console.log(error);
  });
```

But i am getting this error while running :

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at topology.connect (C:\dev\contact-api_bind\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:412:16)
    at ReplSet.<anonymous> (C:\dev\contact-api_bind\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\replset.js:364:11)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
    at ReplSet.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at C:\dev\contact-api_bind\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:631:23
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\dev\contact-api_bind\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:357:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
    at Server.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\dev\contact-api_bind\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:562:21)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\dev\contact-api_bind\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:316:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\dev\contact-api_bind\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:160:13)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...**
```

Comment: Which version of mongoose ? Also, is that all in your code example, do you have a `close()` method on your code ?

Comment: Hi Wan, issue got resolved. Actually my organization was using proxy server to block the connection. Worked fine when i tried with my personal machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got Solved. Actually my organization was using a proxy server to block the connection.

Worked perfectly fine with my personal machine.